Unitree Go1 unitree_legged_sdk 'make' error
I try to build the unitree_legged_sdk v3.8.6 on my virtual Ubuntu 22.04 and follow the instructions:
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make

But when I try to execute the command 'make' I get the following error:
.../unitree_legged_sdk/lib/cpp/amd64/libunitree_legged_sdk.a(loop.cpp.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined hidden symbol `_ZTCN5boost10wrapexceptINS_17bad_function_callEEE0_NS_16exception_detail10clone_implINS3_19error_info_injectorIS1_EEEE' can not be used when making a PIE object

/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/example_position.dir/build.make:97: example_position] Error 1

make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:125: CMakeFiles/example_position.dir/all] Error 2

make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2

How I can solve this issue?
Thank you.

Please don't edit a solution into your question as this will make it hard to find for future readers. Instead, scroll all the way down and post an answer. You can accept your own answer after 48 hours.

I edited the CMakeLists.txt file of the unitree_legged_sdk and added the following line under add_executable(example_position example/example_position.cpp): target_link_options(example_position PRIVATE "-no-pie")
No error anymore. Did this for every other target as well. Ran it on the Go1 and it worked.
